# group presentation with circularly shifted relator

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-presentation, permutation-cycles, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G=\langle S \mid R_1 \cup R_2 \cup R_3 \rangle$ be a group presentation with $S=\{a,b,c\}$, $R_1=\{aa{^{\text{-}1}}, bb{^{\text{-}1}}, c^2\}$, $R_2$ the set of all circular shifts of the word $w=a{^{\text{-}1}}bab{^{\text{-}1}}c$ and the set $R_3$ all circular shifts of the reverse inverse of $w$, $w^R=c{^{\text{-}1}}ba{^{\text{-}1}}b{^{\text{-}1}}a=cba{^{\text{-}1}}b{^{\text{-}1}}a$.

So $R_2 = {\{a{^{\text{-}1}}bab{^{\text{-}1}}c,
\\\\ ca{^{\text{-}1}}bab{^{\text{-}1}},
\\\\ b{^{\text{-}1}}ca{^{\text{-}1}}ba,
\\\\ ab{^{\text{-}1}}ca{^{\text{-}1}}b,
\\\\ bab{^{\text{-}1}}ca{^{\text{-}1}}
\}}$

and $R_3 = {\{cba{^{\text{-}1}}b{^{\text{-}1}}a,
\\\\ acba{^{\text{-}1}}b{^{\text{-}1}},
\\\\ b{^{\text{-}1}}acba{^{\text{-}1}},
\\\\ a{^{\text{-}1}}b{^{\text{-}1}}acb,
\\\\ ba{^{\text{-}1}}b{^{\text{-}1}}ac
\}}$

There must be some much more concise way of defining $R_2$ and $R_3$. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: But circularly shifting a relator does not change the group presented, so $R_2$ and $R_3$ could both be just one word.

Comment: Note: use `\mid` for proper horizontal spacing in group presentation.

Comment: Also there is not need to include $aa^{-1}$ and $bb^{-1}$ in $R_1$. They are tautological. So $G = \langle a,b,c \mid c^2,w \rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, we have
$$G = \langle a,b,c \mid c^2,w \rangle,$$
which simplifies to
$$G \cong \langle a,b \mid (ba^{-1}b^{-1}a)^2\rangle \cong \langle a,b \mid [a,b]^2\rangle,$$
which is a lot more concise than your version!